# Is there any way to convert .mp4 format audio to .wav format just in memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, audio-converter

I'm developing a WPF application, where I have to play audio. I receive the audio data in `.mp4` format (in a byte array) and the only restriction is that I can't write it out to the hard disk.

I found couple of solutions for playing the `.mp4` format, for example with `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer`, but I can't give a byte array, or stream to this library, to play the audio. It just accepts the file path.

Then I found the `System.Media.SoundPlayer`, which can play audio from a stream, but just in `.wav` format. I started to search for solutions to convert from mp4 to wav. I found the `NAudio` library and I could make the conversion the following way:

```
using (var data = new MediaFoundationReader(filePath)) {
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(stream, data);
}
```

The problem with this is that I can instantiate the `MediaFoundationReader` just with a file path parameter. I didn't find any way to create it without using files. I think this was also a dead end.

So, any suggestion would be helpful about how can I convert audio in memory, or maybe how can I play directly the `.mp4` file from a byte array or stream?

Comment: May be you can get the code from github and try to add a constructor to `MediaFoundationReader` class to take a stream. I guess, it would anyway be opening the stream once it takes the file, so you can pass a stream and continue from there.

Comment: Yes, I already checked the code of that library, it wouldn't be so easy to modify the code, maybe I'll try, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution which converts to an `.mp3` format, but it can also convert to `.wav`. I could use the uwp transcode API the following way:

```
public static async void ConvertMp4ToMp3(byte[] mp4Data, Action<Stream> doneCallback) {
    MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
    var inputStream = new MemoryRandomAccessStream(mp4Data);
    var outputStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    MediaTranscoder transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();

    PrepareTranscodeResult prepareOperation = await transcoder.PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync(inputStream, outputStream, profile);
    if (prepareOperation.CanTranscode) {
        //start to convert
        var transcodeOperation = prepareOperation.TranscodeAsync();

        //registers completed event handler 
        transcodeOperation.Completed += (IAsyncActionWithProgress<double> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus status) => {
            asyncInfo.GetResults();
            var stream = outputStream.AsStream();
            stream.Position = 0;
            doneCallback(stream);
        };
    } else {
        doneCallback(null);
    }
}
```

The imports:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Media.Transcoding;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

And the `MemoryRandomAccessStream` is just an implementation of the `IRandomAccesStream` interface and can be found [here](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any audio formats witn NAudio

See samples like :[How to convert a MP3 file to WAV with NAudio in WinForms C#](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/696/how-to-convert-a-mp3-file-to-wav-with-naudio-in-winforms-c-sharp)
with several methods like **MediaFoundationReader**

Comment: Yes, the sample code what I posted in the question is doing this conversion. Maybe I wasn't very clear, that I do NOT want to write the audio data to a file in the hard disk. Not even for couple of milliseconds! The problem with the MediaFoundationReader is that I can instantiate just with a file path parameter. In the samples what you gave, every example is doing the conversion from a file. So do you know how can I do it directly from the memory without using files?